# How to store value in html without showing on page

Tags: html, google-app-engine, jinja2

I'm using Jinja2 and Google App Engine.

I identify my models with integer num:

```
class TestModel(db.Model):
    value = db.StringProperty()
    num = db.IntegerProperty()
```

and have a class for editing the value:

```
class Edit(Handler):
    def get(self):
        #show input box with value, let user edit value, render page with num


    def post(self):
        #get new value, filter database for model instance BY NUM and replace with new value
```

I need to store num on the page so I can retrieve it for the post method but I don't want the page to display it.

I tried:

```
<span name = "num" value = "{{num}}"></span>
```

and in the post method I have

```
 num = self.request.get('num')
 logging.error("NUM: %s" % num)
```

But when I run this, num doesn't show in the logs (I have "NUM:  ") and I get

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

When I render the page, the source code shows that num is there. Why isn't this code properly retrieving num?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried putting the field into a hidden input element. i.e.

```
<input type="hidden" name="..." value="..."/>
```

Also make sure that the value you are trying to retrieve in your post is within the form tags.

Comment: That was it, thank you. Why does the input tag work and not the span tag?